# How to get the matched nodes using Matching.decode() in PyMatching?

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, toric-code

In the module [matching.py](https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching/blob/master/src/pymatching/matching.py) of [PyMatching](https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching), it is possible to construct Matching objects to decode matching graphs using the minimum-weight perfect matching decoder.
The `decode()` method returns the most probable correction and "The sum of the weights of the edges in the minimum-weight perfect matching".

Is it possible to get the matched nodes of the graph ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are correct that PyMatching outputs the edges in the solution, but not the pairs of detection events. You can find a valid pairing of in Python by tracing the paths between detection events using the edges in the solution, but I agree it would be nicer if a fast method for this was already provided in the API. This is a nice feature I'd like to add at some point, and I've just opened an issue for it on GitHub: https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching/issues/34

Comment: Update: Version 2.0 of PyMatching does now include  `pymatching.Matching.decode_to_matched_dets_array` and `pymatching.Matching.decode_to_matched_dets_dict` methods, which output pairs of matched detection events in the solution: https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching/releases/tag/v2.0.0